# Database design - keep track of latest snapshot of user submitted data

Tags: sql, database, performance

I am currently developing an application which basically allows the users to submit data online and store the data.  We assign the data a unique ID so that later on the user can retrieve the data by IDs, and modify or delete the data. But most of time we expect the user to just keep submitting new data (and we assign a new ID for the new data).  We need to keep track of all the historical data, so if user modifies/deletes data we never modify/delete the original data, but save a new snapshot of the data to current tables.  We always retrieve the latest snapshot of the data (per unique ID).

Currently we get the latest snapshot in this way - group the data by unique ID and sort by db primary key, and then find the Max(db primary key) entry.  I am thinking to add a status flag to the snapshots to indicate which snapshot is active, so that we can simplify the SQL queries.  But we were told by our DBA  that this is bad for performance (or complicate the process) because this means every time the user modifies the data we need to have an extra step to deactivate the current snapshot, and update operation is more expensive than search for Database.  But to me the SQL queries for fetching data are getting way too complicated now because we have snapshots for everything so we need to group snapshots almost for any data and it is also error-prone when we try to retrieve multiple types of submitted data and the data are related (we have to be very careful about where in the sql to get the latest snapshots).  So I want to get some opinions about this issue.  Any opinions or suggestions?  or maybe just educate me why having a status flag is a bad idea.

Comment: you should learn \ read up on database design fundamentals

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  But I am not a DBA or DB architect , and my job is not to design database schema so this won't be on top of my to-do list ...

Comment: what is your job \ function? Also, if you think they are getting too complicated they probably are doing something wrong or very inefficiently. Suggest you go back to basics, break your queries down, rather than use sub queries use CTE's and temp tables where required, but also speak with your DBA's

Comment: I am just a Java programmer and currently developing the middle tier.  I was not involved in DB design and I did not create the SQL queries either.  That's why when I found how complicated DB is designed and the SQL queries were written, I was shocked and think there must be something wrong.  I'll see if I can have a chance to directly talk to our DBA.

Comment: database design and development isnt that hard. the principals have been the same for decades. speak with your DBA's run SQL Profiler if you need to look at the queries and then you can tune from there.

Answer (score 0):

A status flag is one of the best ways to accomplish what you want. Actually using Max(db primary key) is using more processing power than trying to find a binary value (0 or 1).

Comment: That was my thought too... unfortunately it seems I am the only one in my team to think so...

Answer (score 0):

This topic looks for me as audit table tracking. The best is to have triggers on tables and write changes like insert, update, delete into separete tables.

e.g. You have table CUSTOMER and **AUDIT_**CUSTOMER.
In CUSTOMER you have current data and in AUDIT_CUSTOMER whole history.

Audit tables depend on design have structure like this

```
DT - date and time
USER_NAME - user changed data
KIND - I,U,D (insert, update, delete)
oryginal_table_fields_here
```

You simply insert data in the triggers and you can simply retrive current data and you can back in time if you want by changing only source table from NORMAL to AUDIT and filter by DT

Comment: that's an interesting idea.  I don't know why we don't do this in our company... we used to keep all historical data and current data in one table..